# Routing a Google AppEngine cron job to a specific version of a module

Tags: java, xml, google-app-engine, cron

I have problems when trying to route the cron job to a specific version of a module. Module batcher contains the cron.xml file. Inside the file I have:

```
<cron>
    <url>/_user/tags/deleteOld?page=0&amp;pageSize=50</url>
    <description>deletes user's old tags</description>
    <schedule>every saturday 21:00</schedule>
    <timezone>Europe/Helsinki</timezone>   
    <target>v4-dot-batcher</target>  
</cron>
```

This works ok and the cron job is routed to the batcher module version v4 correctly. 
Now, if I try to redirect this cron job on another module called mules:

```
    <cron>
        <url>/_user/tags/deleteOld?page=0&amp;pageSize=50</url>
        <description>deletes user's old tags</description>
        <schedule>every saturday 21:00</schedule>
        <timezone>Europe/Helsinki</timezone>   
        <target>v4-dot-mules</target>  
    </cron>
```

This does not work anymore, as the request is always sent to a default version (called test) of the module and not on v4.

Is it because the cron.xml is in the batcher module or is this problem related to the dispatch.xml? I have not set anything related to route "/_user/tags/deleteOld" in dispatch.xml of the mules module.

Looking at the Logs, the protoPayload contains:

```
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"
versionId: "test"
startTime: "2017-05-29T16:45:00.628537Z"
endTime: "2017-05-29T16:45:00.642901Z"
latency: "0.014364s"
megaCycles: "11"
method: "GET"
resource: "/_user/tags/deleteOld?page=0&pageSize=50"
httpVersion: "HTTP/1.1"
status: 404
responseSize: "234"
userAgent: "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
urlMapEntry: "unused"
host: "v4-dot-mules.testapp.appspot.com"
taskQueueName: "__cron"
finished: true

}
```

The configuration of the v4 for mules looks like:

```
runtime: java7
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F4
inbound_services:
  - warmup
handlers:
  - url: '/.*'
    script: unused
    secure: always
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: 1
  min_pending_latency: 5s
  max_pending_latency: 15s
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
```

Any ideas about this? Much appreciated!

Comment: Is your `v4-dot-mules` version running and handling at least some of the traffic?

Comment: Side question: why are you trying to route to a specific version of that service?

Comment: Side comment: the cron config is an app-level config, not a service-level one, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556781/gae-cron-job-shuts-down-unexpectedly/41583956#41583956. So it shouldn't really matter from execution prospective which service contains that config (it may matter from the deployment prospective - simply deploying the service holding the cron config may not updated the cron jobs, they may need to be explicitly updated).

Comment: Yes it's running.  I am trying to route for testing purposes.

Comment: What's in your `dispatch.xml` file? (which, BTW, is also an app-level config)

Comment: Is `v4` the default version of the `batcher` module by any chance?

Comment: No v4 is not the default version.

Comment: In dispatch.xml I have configured other routes and nothing related to the url /_user/tags/deleteOld.